# Summing up decreases in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like   (id, disk_id,  disk_usage,  time_measured)

Each row corresponding to disk usage at a point in time.    A disk will have many rows.  id is just a primary key column.

I want to sum up the intervals where there's a *decrease* between rows for dates between 1/1/2016 and 3/1/2016.

I.e. if disk_usage for a particular was 10GB on 1/1/2016 and 5GB on 1/2/2016,  I want to include 5GB in my sum.     If usage *increases* between two timepoints,  I want to ignore that interval.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Well... that is good task for windowing functions. That is not available for mysql. What you can do? For each row, you can ask for previous record - newest, but older then the one you are querying for. To do that you need to self-join the table. Let's determine previous date:

```
select max(b.time_measured)
from the_table as a 
 join the_table as b 
  on a.disk_id = b.disk_id and a.time_measured > b.time_measured
group by a.disk_id
```

Now you have that date. I have no idea if your MySQL understands subselects - if so you can do that that:

```
select a.*, b.*
from the_table as a 
 join the_table as b 
  on a.disk_id = b.disk_id
where b.time_measured = (
 select max(b.time_measured)
 from the_table as a 
  join the_table as b 
   on a.disk_id = b.disk_id and a.time_measured > b.time_measured
 group by a.disk_id)
group by a.disk_id
```

Other option is to do that in your program.

Comment: How does this sum up the decreases?    It looks like it finds pairs of rows where one row immediately preceeds the other (half the battle?)

Comment: You have two rows in hand - so you can compare, filter... To me - that is the answer.